# Angular Child Route not changing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, routes

I am designing a website with angular4, and have a component that inside uses the @angular/material sidenav. Within that sidenav i have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

my app.module has all the necessary imports and declarations, I have a app-routing module that contains the following code for the component:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'reg',
    component: RegComponent,
    children: [
        { path: ':info', component: RegInfoComponent },
        { path: ':ther', component: RegTherComponent }
    ]},
];
```

I have two span objects to open the sidenav:
`<span class="label label-info" [routerLink]="['/reg', 'info']" (click)=sidenav.open() style="cursor: pointer;">Info</span>`

and
`<span class="label label-info" [routerLink]="['/reg', 'ther']" (click)=sidenav.open() style="cursor: pointer;">Ther</span>`

The sidenav opens fine, but only loads the html template from RegInfoComponent, if i click the `ther` link, it still loads the html template from RegInfoComponent, but the URL does change.

At first i thought it was maybe because its inside the angular material sidenav, so i placed the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` below the link, and it still wouldnt change.

I'm not sure what i've done wrong that the router-outlet is not displaying the correct child information, hoping somebody can help with this? Thanks.

## Update

The code for RegInfoComponent:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reg-info',
  templateUrl: './reg-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reg-info.component.css']
})
export class RegInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute,
              router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and the code for the RegTherComponent

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reg-ther',
  templateUrl: './reg-ther.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reg-ther.component.css']
})
export class RegTherComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute,
              router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is just your typing of the question, but your `click=...` does not have any quotes around the parameters. Probably doesn't solve your problem, but could be an issue.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `RegInfoComponent` and `RegTherComponent`?

Comment: Noted, and code being from the .ts file? The html file just contains a single <p> line to check its working.

Comment: Are you trying to load these components into the sidenav itself or open a page and have the side nav pop out at the same time?

Comment: Im trying to load these components into the sidenav itself while staying on the same page. It works already but only loads the template from `RegInfoComponent`. If i click the `RegTherComponent` link, it opens the sidenav but has the template from `RegInfoComponent`..

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need a routerLink, as you're not navigating away from the page. Instead you just want to load different html into the nav based on which link is clicked. I don't see a way to pass parameters to the sidenav which makes this difficult. Perhaps multiple sidenav's would solve them problem?

Comment: The documentation shows support for upto 2 sidenavs, but on different sides, and i will implement 4 different html templates to be loaded into the sidenav. You are right in that it can be done without a routerlink and i did that by using an ngIf statement calling the selector of the specific template when it needed to be loaded. I wanted to do the routerLink because on the main template, there are many segments, each segment has a link to open the sidenav and load a particular section within the template of RegInfoComponent, RegTherComponent etc...

Comment: Actually just saying that, I could on each template to be loaded in the sidenav create lots of small sections, each with an ngIf condition, so the links on the main component activate a function that will then just display the desired part of that specific component. I will try that in a bit and see how it goes. It just seemed cleaner to me to use a RouterLink,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your router config is incorrect

you are using variable segments with `:info` and `:ther` so the first one (`:info`) will always match first (and the RegInfoComponent gets instantiated), and therefore `RegTherComponent` will never be instantiated

You need to do something like this

```
<span class="label label-info" [routerLink]="['/reg/info']" (click)=sidenav.open() style="cursor: pointer;">Info</span>
<span class="label label-info" [routerLink]="['/reg/ther']" (click)=sidenav.open() style="cursor: pointer;">Ther</span>
```

and then the router config should be

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'reg',
    component: RegComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'info', component: RegInfoComponent },
        { path: 'ther', component: RegTherComponent }
    ]},
];
```

Comment: I think you're right about the routes revision, but the routerLink needs to be the same as in OPs code; separated into parts.

Comment: Why does it need to be separated into parts?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I re-wrote my code using the idea from my last comment under my original post as I think it actually works better for my needs, just mocked up your solution and that worked fine too i think, but I did change a few other stuff that I lost track of..