# Child route is not activating in Angular 11

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application in Angular 11. I have a route that have a children that can be activated if you want to, clicking on a button with the `routerLink` on it. In other words, the goal is to navigate to the child route, not presenting the child route inside the parent using `router-outlet`.

Right now, when you click on it nothing happens and you stay at the same page, even when the browser url change correctly.

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/calculator/calculator.module').then(m => m.CalculatorModule)
      },
    ]
  },

];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**calculator-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-route-1',
    component: Route1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'my-route-2',
    component: Route2Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

**route2.component.html**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="child">
  Go to child
</button>
```

The browser url changes to `/my-route-2/child`, but, nothing else.

**Expected behavior:**

1. I would like to navigate to the "child" component.
2. The "child" component needs to be activated with "my-route-2" as its parent.
3. If you try to access to `"/my-route-2"` the `Route2Component` is activated, and if try to access to `"/my-route-2/child"` the `ChildComponent` should be activated.
4. The intention is to navigate to the child route without presenting the child route inside the parent's html file using `router-outlet`.

I have followed this advice:

1. [Angular Child Route not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384367/angular-child-route-not-changing)

I have tried:

```
routerLink="child"
routerLink="my-route-2/child"
routerLink="/my-route-2/child"
routerLink="./child"
routerLink="./my-route-2/child"
```

My goal is to navigate to the child route properly, changing the component/content on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807154/angular-lazy-loading-a-module-inside-module-with-a-child-route The answer may be as simple as adding <router-outlet></router-outlet> to Route1Component

Comment: @RobinWebb As I said at the introduction of my question, I don't want to use `router-outlet` because that will render the child on the same screen of the parent and that's not what I'm looking for. Maybe my goal is not possible? I don't know, any idea to achieve the same result?

Comment: @RRGT19 Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue!